# Django Rest Framework - permission to create

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a CRUD in django rest framework and to control the permissions I'm using permission classes. Here is the permission class I created for the CRUD. This works well for update and delete:

```
class LinkAssetPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Link access not allowed.'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.content.delivery.owner == request.user and obj.content.delivery.can_change
```

My Problem if that this class does not work well for my create view:

```
class AssetCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Link a new asset
    """
    queryset = Asset.objects.none()
    serializer_class = AssetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.DjangoModelPermissions, LinkAssetPermission, )
```

When `obj.content.delivery.can_change` returns false I cannot create, update or delete model objects. The same for `obj.content.delivery.owner == request.user` . I can only create, update or delete when the user is the owner. All this works as I want for update and delete, just for create that it is not working. Probably because I don't have the object yet, that's the core of my question.

The object exists when creating and I have also tried to just `return False` at `has_object_permission` and I still can create the record.

Should I create a new permission class for the insert or should I change something in my view?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I mean, this method obj.content.delivery.can_change returns false and I can create a new record. My idea is when this can_chance returns false none records can be created, updated or deleted

Comment: At the time of creating, there is no `obj` present before proceeding with `create`. Which `obj` are you referring to?

Comment: Actually there is, I have debugged. I have also tried to just return false the has_object_permission and I can still create the record

Comment: `obj` passed to this function refers to object being accessed at the time of detail requests. At the time of `create`, this function is not called as no object is being accessed but being created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what I had to do. Here is my new permission class:

```
class LinkAssetPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Link access not allowed.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            content = Content.objects.get(pk=request.parser_context["kwargs"]["content_id"])
        except:
            return False

        return content.delivery.owner == request.user and content.delivery.can_change

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.content.delivery.owner == request.user and obj.content.delivery.can_change
```

On create the method has_object_permission is not considered but the has_permission is. So I retrieve the parameter sent from the urls.py, query and check the properties of the object I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`has_object_permissions()` gets called whenever `.get_object()` method is called in a generic view i.e. a particular resource is being accessed.

Now, all the `detail` requests (`retrieve`, `update`, `delete`) access a particular resource/object, it works. For `create` requests, `get_object()` method does not get called, so it does not work in your case.

For handling `create` requests, you can create another serializer where there is validations for the above 2 conditions. And then change your permission classes to work for `detail` requests only.

Comment: Just read that on the doc's as well, I'm still looking for the answer for the CreateView

Comment: Maybe you can create another serializer for create and then limit permissions check to handle  `detail` requests only.